# vnc-server centos 7 error failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded

Tags: linux, centos7, vnc

I try to install vnc-server on my centos 7 server by following the steps below:

1) We install vnc-server

```html
sudo yum install tigervnc-server
```

After, you’ve installed the program, login with the user you want to run the VNC program and issue the below command in terminal in order to configure a password for the VNC server.

```html
su - your_user  # If you want to configure VNC server to run under this user directly from CLI without switching users from GUI
$ vncpasswd
```

add a VNC service configuration file for your user via a daemon configuration file placed in systemd directory tree. In order to copy the VNC template file you need to run the following command with root privileges.

```html
cp /lib/systemd/system/vncserver@.service  /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:1.service
```

On the next step edit the copied VNC template configuration file from /etc/systemd/system/ directory and replace the values to reflect your user as shown in the below

```html
vi /etc/systemd/system/vncserver@\:1.service


[Unit]
Description=Remote desktop service (VNC)
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'
ExecStart=/sbin/runuser -l my_user -c "/usr/bin/vncserver %i -geometry 1280x720"
PIDFile=/home/my_user/.vnc/%H%i.pid
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || :'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After you’ve made the proper changes to VNC service file, reload systemd system initialization program to pick up the new vnc configuration file and start the TigerVNC server.

```html
systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl start vncserver@:1
# systemctl status vncserver@:1
# systemctl enable vncserver@:1
```

Obtaining the following error

```html
systemctl daemon-reload
[root@ns363691 ~]# systemctl start vncserver@:1
Job for vncserver@:1.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status vncserver@:1.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@ns363691 ~]# systemctl status vncserver@:1
● vncserver@:1.service - Remote desktop service (VNC)
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@:1.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: resources) since mié 2019-11-13 02:09:07 CET; 14s ago
  Process: 7605 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/runuser -l root -c /usr/bin/vncserver %i -geometry 1280x720 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7593 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c /usr/bin/vncserver -kill %i > /dev/null 2>&1 || : (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

nov 13 02:09:04 ns363691 systemd[1]: Starting Remote desktop service (VNC)...
nov 13 02:09:07 ns363691 systemd[1]: Can't open PID file /home/root/.vnc/ns363691:1.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
nov 13 02:09:07 ns363691 systemd[1]: Failed to start Remote desktop service (VNC).
nov 13 02:09:07 ns363691 systemd[1]: Unit vncserver@:1.service entered failed state.
nov 13 02:09:07 ns363691 systemd[1]: vncserver@:1.service failed.
```

Any idea why the service does not start, what is this doing wrong? :(

Comment: Do you have directory `/home/root/.vnc/`?

Comment: The /home / root.vnv directory does not exist.  I do not use the root user as a vnc user that is a terrible idea.

Comment: Any alternative that works better and has fewer problems than a vnc-server?